# Assign html class to generated Django form input elements

Tags: django

I have this form:

```
class ZeroIntegrationConfigForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = ZeroIntegrationEntry
    fields = ['tab_title', 'description', 'country', 'operations',
              'locale', 'company_name']
```

That I generate with:

```
  <form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
  </form>
```

But I can't figure out / find how to assign html class to each input element generated, is the only way to do this writing the html manually for each element?

Comment: read about ```widget_tweaks``` and use ```{% render_field field_name class+='your_class' %}```

Comment: or you can also apply classes directly inside ModelForm using ```widgets```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add **init** to your ModelForm like this:

```
class ZeroIntegrationConfigForm(forms.Form):
# Your declared form fields here
...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ZeroIntegrationConfigForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for visible in self.visible_fields():
            visible.field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'your-class'
```

if you want to set a different class for each tag you can add ' if ' in the ' for '